# Error in Android Studio with my system

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple app. It just has a splashscreen, introactivity, overview, then main page with image buttons the image button will intent to modules with images.

> 07-12 10:06:41.819 22293-22293/com.example.chan.data E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering 07-12 10:06:56.729 22293-22293/com.example.chan.data E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 1209328-byte allocation. 07-12 10:06:56.734 22293-22293/com.example.chan.data E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.chan.data, PID: 22293 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chan.data/com.antonio.chan.data.disaster4}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2033) at com.antonio.chan.data.disaster4.onCreate(disaster4.java:22) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5453) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2033)  at com.antonio.chan.data.disaster4.onCreate(disaster4.java:22)  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5453)  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513) at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889) at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436) at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133) at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2033)  at com.antonio.chan.data.disaster4.onCreate(disaster4.java:22)  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5453)  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

XML that gives the error:

```
package com.antonio.chan.data;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class disaster4 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageButton btnsim;
    ImageButton btnmod;

    public ImageButton but1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disaster4);

        btnsim = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.landslide_sim);
        btnsim.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnmod = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.landslide_mod);
        btnmod.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==btnmod) {
            Intent IntentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(disaster4.this,disaster4_module4.class );
            startActivity(IntentLoadNewActivity);
        }
        if (v==btnsim){
            Intent IntentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(disaster4.this, disaster4_sim.class );
            startActivity(IntentLoadNewActivity);
        }
    }
}
```

JAVA:

```
package com.antonio.chan.data;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class disaster4 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageButton btnsim;
    ImageButton btnmod;

    public ImageButton but1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disaster4);

        btnsim = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.landslide_sim);
        btnsim.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnmod = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.landslide_mod);
        btnmod.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==btnmod) {
            Intent IntentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(disaster4.this,disaster4_module4.class );
            startActivity(IntentLoadNewActivity);
        }

        if (v==btnsim){
            Intent IntentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(disaster4.this, disaster4_sim.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear. what you are asking

Comment: Please enter XML, you've pasted something else

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Out of Memory Exception`. Try handling it.

Comment: how can I handle it?